# Xcode Source Compiling Order Issue

Tags: xcode

I am working on a fork of the Xbox HID project (to allow greater configuration of the controller) and came across a really strange issue.

The project is three projects, which I have grouped together under a workspace, which works well, it compiles them in order (kext, daemon and prefpane) and all works.

However, I decided to uncrustify the code (thanks Alcatraz!) and standardise the names and locations of source files. This required me to update the project as file paths changed.

Once this was all completed the PrefPane wouldn't load. For some reason it was instantiating and sending `initWithBundle` to an object that was NOT the `File's Owner` in the XIB.

After a lot of debugging and hair-pulling I discovered the object it was instantiating also happened to be the first file listed in the Compile Sources build phase. Once I moved the correct file to the top of that list the PrefPane once again launched and worked as expected.

That seems wrong, why does it need to compile this particular class first... better yet, why is it picking up only the first compiled class instead of the one specified in the XIB?

I am using Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e) under OSX 10.9.5, however, I am using the OSX 10.6 SDK and have 10.6 as the deployment target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having some other issues with the project in question, so I rebuilt all three projects and this issue went away.

I am guessing there was some sort of issue with the Xcode project itself as I believe it was probably upgraded from at least two previous major versions of Xcode.

Lesson here seems to be, rebuild the project files themselves and see if that fixes the issues!

Comment: What other issues were you having and did you ever find out what might have caused this? I am seeing the same thing and rebuilding the project (with 8 targets) is a day-long daunting task that I would rather avoid. It works by compiling the principal class first, but I am wondering if there are other problems lurking if I choose to not rebuild it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay with my reply... been playing too much Neverwinter and not enough coding so haven't been around SO as much as I should be. Sadly, I have no idea what what original issue is, just rebuilding the entire project from scratch fixed it. I am guessing something went wonky in one of XCode's project files, but no idea what or where... sorry! :(